# Bluetooth disconnects with Miracast

Tags: bluetooth, lg, miracast

When I share my phone screen with an LG monitor through Miracast, the Bluetooth disconnects and I need to reconnect it to keep the music playing.

How do I stop this?

Comment: This is behavior-by-design, although a choice to the user in this would be nice. If your phone's casting settings don't offer an option to keep BT enabled, than you can only look for a workaround. A reasonable workaround is to have an automation app automatically connect to you BT device once disconnected. The problem is the trigger: how to detect screen is being casted?